# Prevent resizing of windows media player(when embedded inside mfc application) when outer window is resized

Tags: mfc, wmp, wmplayer

Hi stackoverflow community,

I am using the WMPHost Sample from the win 7 sdk.
What i want is that when i resize the outer window the windows media player(activex control) should not automatically adjust itself.Instead the video should be clipped.
Do i need to look into the way how activeX control is created or how the host window handles it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at how the host window handles resizing. Most likely it resizes its child window "to fit"; you may be able to simply remove that code to have your control clipped instead.

You should think about how to size that control first time: to fit its container, or to contain the full size of its content.